# Nginx redirect loop when redirecting to https

Tags: nginx, https

**If you have the free cloudflare plan, or cloudflare enabled, it will cause an infinite redirect loop.**

I am trying to redirect http to https with nginx. I have tried literally(almost) everything. I have tried regex, 301 redirects and returns.

I am not sure, but it could be something with the config file. I am using Let's Encrypt for SSL and php7.0.5-fpm for processing scripts.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php;

    server_name example.com;

    error_page 500 /500.html;
    error_page 404 /404.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**Edit** Here is the command `ls -lah`:

```
total 44K
drwxrwxrwx 6 root  root  4.0K Feb 28 22:12 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 root  root  4.0K Feb 20 21:19 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 rsudo rsudo  396 Feb 21 15:52 404.php
drwxrwxrwx 8 rsudo rsudo 4.0K Feb 21 15:50 assets
drwxrwxrwx 3 rsudo rsudo 4.0K Feb 21 15:48 backend
-rw-rw-rw- 1 rsudo rsudo  360 Feb 21 18:20 .htaccess
drwxrwxrwx 2 rsudo rsudo 4.0K Feb 21 15:49 includes
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root   612 Feb 28 22:12 index.nginx-debian.html
-rw-rw-rw- 1 rsudo rsudo   21 Feb 21 03:36 info.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 rsudo rsudo 2.4K Feb 21 15:58 login.php
drwxrwxrwx 3 root  root  4.0K Feb 23 23:10 .well-known
```

configuration:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/1.log;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/2.log;   

   server_name example.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/1ssl.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/2ssl.log;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php;

    error_page 500 /500.html;
    error_page 404 /404.php;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

    location / {
        #So lonely...
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see `.well-known` part, are you configuring HTTPS via `Let's Encrypt`? If yes, that part should be put in 80 port.

Comment: The ssl should go into the port 80 block? Also I am using Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you aim at rewriting all http traffic to https, simply go with this configuration:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.example.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

This does a permanent redirect (301) from Port 80 to Port 443. So we can use this part, if no logging or anything else is needed for Port 80.

For the SSL configuration, please review the following part of the configuration:

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name www.example.com;

   ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl-bundle.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl-bundle.key;
   ssl_session_timeout 1d;
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
   # ssl_session_tickets off;

   # openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048
   # ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/SSL/dhparams.pem;

   ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   # commented out. Thanks to user Tom for the advice that Strict-Transport-Security may result in problems with subdomains.
   #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;includeSubdomains; preload";

   root /your/root/;
   index index.html index.htm index.php;

   client_max_body_size 20M;

   location / {
      # your custom config goes here for the "/" location.
   }

   location /doc/ {
       alias /usr/share/doc/;
       autoindex on;
       allow 127.0.0.1;
       deny all;
   }

   location ~/\.ht {
       deny all;
   }
 }
```

Please note: I would suggest generating at least 2048 bit DiffieHellman parameters, or even better 4096. The above SSL config will give your site at least an A rating on SSLLabs.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: corrected ssl_ciphers section as there was a copy&paste problem in the original answer. Thx Jacob for pointing me on this.

Comment: Adding Strict-Transport-Security in the configuration without explaining the effects is a REALLY BAD advice. Worse, with "includeSubdomains" and "preload" you may breaks his subdomains ! (But yes, if he can and want to commit to https, it's a good thing)

Comment: thanks for the comment, I'll edit my answer above with your hints.

Comment: I still get a redirect loop. Should I post what I did?

Comment: have you tried my solution? have you checked to possibly disable (remove symlink(s) ) in sites-enabled? can you post server log files from nginx, so possibly this gives another hint on what's going wrong..

Comment: Once I can get on my computer (tomorrow) I will look at the logs. How do I find the logs for Nginx 1.9.3 on Ubuntu?

Comment: Also on the line with ssl_ciphers you are missing a single quote on that line. The syntax highlighting thinks you're quoting all of the code below it.

Comment: sorry again. I've edited my answer, correcting the line with ssl_ciphers. Indeed a c&p problem.
usually the log files are stored in _/var/log/ngix/_ on Ubuntu systems. You can add "access_log /var/log/nginx/yoursitename-https-access_log;" and
"error_log  /var/log/nginx/yoursitename-https-error_log info;" to your nginx config, so you might get a bit more control on whats going on.

Comment: have you tried my version for the port 80 part? as of now looking at the debug information nginx does your 301 (permanent redirect) but I think it's doing it somehow wrong. please try replacing your return directive to _return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;_

Comment: Still a redirect loop. Updated my answer with the latest details.

Comment: semm0 i will further try your suggestion if the code above is not valid to you.

Comment: to me it looks like the directory /var/www/html/ has the wrog owner as nginx can't read it. Clearly in the log files. It seems to exist but nginx is not allowed to read it. double check owner (use 'ls -lah'), be sure it's set correct corresponding to your nginx user/group. I would delete everything from the config file not necessary for testing. But I suspect a owner permission problem.

Comment: i ran nginx on the root login and it still happens. I will look at logs to see what it says.

Comment: I ran it as root and now it isn't outputting anything.

Comment: Updated my answer. It has just a couple of 301's, no errors, and no logs/errors from ssl. I am running the server as root.

Comment: okay. have you checked directory permissions? otherwise is this a productive live system? possibly someone else can help as I might miss the problem from this point. I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: This will be a production system. I will put the results of the 'ls -lah ' once I get home. I don't really know how to read the output so I will put that there. The ultimate goal is to have all traffic redirected to https and for the server to run on the sudo account.

Comment: It turns out it was a cloudflare issue.

Comment: Okay good to know. Can't remember you mentioned CloudFlare, for future questions please try to give details on all parts / services involved :)

Comment: I didn't think cloudflare was the issue. But now I know to give more details. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's configuring HTTPS via `Let's Encrypt`.
The key point is that you should use 80 port only for `.well-known`, and other part shall be handled in 443.

I put my config examples that works OK

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  location /.well-known/ {
    ...
  }
  location / {
    rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/html;
  ... # The rest of configs you previously put in 80 part
}
```

Comment: Does it say something about https redirecting back to http?

Comment: try ctrl+f5 the page.

Comment: I actually just checked, and the code in the question actually loops when redirecting as well. I don't even know what to do anymore.